# How to handle special characters like "&amp;" in XML Parsing for R?

Tags: html, xml, r

I am a newbie to XML in R So I need help to overcome this problem.

I have following XML

```
hp <- htmlParse('<li> <div class="subtle">Culture &amp; Values</div> <span   
class="notranslate gdBars sm " title="5.0"> <span class="gdBarsSep">Â </span><span  
class="gdBarsSep">Â </span><span class="gdBarsSep">Â </span><span class="gdBarsSep">Â  
</span><span class="gdBarsSep last">Â </span> <span style="width:94.5px" class="sel">
</span> </span>
</li> <li> <div class="subtle">Work/Life Balance</div> <span class="notranslate  
gdBars sm " title="4.0"> <span class="gdBarsSep">Â </span><span class="gdBarsSep">Â  
</span><span class="gdBarsSep">Â </span><span class="gdBarsSep">Â </span><span 
class="gdBarsSep last">Â </span> <span style="width:76.5px" class="sel"></span> </span> 
</li>')
```

In the above XML, I am trying to grab "title" value when div has a value "Culture & Values" using following R code but is not giving me expected output. I am getting Null value as output although I was expecting "5.0" as output.

```
CultureValues<-unlist(xpathApply(hp,"//div[text()='Culture &amp; Values']/following- 
sibling::span", xmlGetAttr,"title"))
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please answer if somebody have solution to this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
> xpathSApply(hp, "//*[contains(text(),'Culture ')]/following-sibling::span/@title")
title 
"5.0"
```

or change your query to

```
> CultureValues<-unlist(xpathApply(hp,"//div[text()='Culture & Values']/following-sibling::span", xmlGetAttr,"title"))
> CultureValues
[1] "5.0"
```

`&amp;` is just the entity name for `&`

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the response. First Solution may not work when you will be having div value "Culture" not "Culture &amp; Values". I tried the second solution but it is still giving me null output. Any specific reason, the second solution is not working for me,

Comment: Im not sure why it doesnt work for you. It works on linux and seems to work on windows for me.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Your reply is helpful to me.

Comment: There is more info on how libxml handles entities here http://xmlsoft.org/entities.html